# NetSocket write exception when network becomes unreachable

Tags: sockets, netty, vert.x, shutdown

I am using `NetSocket` class to write data to a TCP server. When the TCP server gracefully shuts down, socket's close handler is invoked and everything is working correctly. However, when I cut off the network during execution, I get success on write handler. In pure Java I would get something like this `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe.`

Is this a bug and how to implement this? I would like to avoid implementing my own timeout and rather have the info when the socket is abruptly closed.

This is the code I'm using for writing:

```
socket.write(requestCommandBuffer, writeBuffer -> {
    if (writeBuffer.succeeded()) {
        //I always get success here, even when other side abruptly closes the socket
        LOG.info("Successful write.");
    } else {
        LOG.error("Failed to write.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Does every write after cutting off the network succeed? Are you only sending one? You should be getting a channel closed exception

Comment: I am writing only once per socket, but I have multiple sockets open in the same pool. I always get success, but of course nothing in response since there is no other side and that's where the socket blocks. It seems that the close handler is being called after 25-30 seconds, but I would expect some kind of an exception immediately.